# attributes of Mainwindow from childWindow

Tags: python, qt, parent-child, mainwindow

How can I make a childWindow access and/or modify an attribute from his MainWindow?

I have a MainWindow that opens different childWindows, dependeing on the pressed button on the MainWindow.

I would like any of the childWindows to be able to modify some attributes of the MainWindow, but I cannot get the good way to access them.

Comment: See documentation for `QWidget::parentWidget` - http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#parentWidget

Comment: @UmNyobe attributes of widget. It is not related to sig/slot. See documentation - http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum

Answer (score 1):

When defining your widget or window (your window is possibly just a QWidget), specify it's parent in the **init**-Method (just pass the parent-widget).

After that, you could use the parentWdiget-Method or simply set a "link" to the parent-widget in an attribute of the child-window.

See http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QWidget.html

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a reference (self) to your childwindow.